# How to merge Cross platform Phonegap app html files without affecting native code

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform

I am working on a cros platform phonegap app. Basically it is working on Android,iOS, Windows phone. Usually i am doing edits on root WWW folder and run terminal command

```
phonegap run  android
phonegap run  iOS
```

It creates projects for each platform. But if i do a platform specific change in native code , "run" command will replace changes. Is there any standard way to sync changes.

Comment: which platform specific changes in native code you do? can't you create plugins for that native code?

Comment: I have edit minsdk version. It changed after "phonegap run android" to previous values.

Comment: you can change the minsdk using a preference, so I think, as it doesn't exists, it might be overwriting your change with the default value, try setting it on your config.xml <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />